# Opening a Word document in a new window

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I have been programming add-in for Microsoft Office Word. I need to open an existing document in a **new** window Word. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you can use it like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253215/open-and-modify-word-document

Comment: Thank you, but this method only works if the first document is edited (or not empty). Otherwise, a second document opens in the first window.

Comment: link shared by Sven should work, can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

try this code, if it is achieved your requirement,else please ask.

```
 public void OpenExistDoc(string docName)
    {
        object fileName = docName;
        object oMissing = Type.Missing;
        this.Application.Documents.Open(ref fileName, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing
            , oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
    }


 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OpenExistDoc("your file");
    }
```