# Convert Word to PDF in background process either via c# or IronPython

Tags: c#, ms-word, pdf-generation, ironpython

I have found many examples online about converting word (.docx) file to .pdf file.

It works fine when I run from UI thread.
But the moment I execute it on background process. then it fails.
Is there some way to convert Word to PDF via background process execution ?

Below are the IronPython and c# code that works on UI thread.

**IronPython:**

```python
import sys
import clr
import System
from System.Text import StringBuilder
from System.IO import DirectoryInfo, File, FileInfo, Path, StreamWriter

clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word as Word

def ConvertWordToPDF(wordDocFullPath):
    """
    <Script>
    <Author>SNI</Author>
    <Description>Converts Word document to PDF.</Description>
    <Parameters>
    <Parameter name="wordDocFullPath" type="string">Word document full path.</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    <ReturnValue type="string">PDF full path</ReturnValue>
    </Script>
    """   
    wordDocInfo = FileInfo(wordDocFullPath)
    pdfFullPath = Path.Combine(wordDocInfo.DirectoryName, wordDocInfo.Name.TrimEnd(wordDocInfo.Extension.ToCharArray()) + '.pdf')

    word_application = Word.ApplicationClass()
    word_application.visible = False

    wordDocument = word_application.Documents.Open(wordDocFullPath);
    if wordDocument:
        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfFullPath, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        wordDocument.Close()
        word_application.Quit()
        word_application = None
    else:
        print 'failed to initialize word document'

    print pdfFullPath
    return pdfFullPath`
```

**c# code:**

```cs
public string Convert(string wordDocPath)
{
    string pdfPath = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = null;
        Document doc = null;

        // C# doesn't have optional arguments so we'll need a dummy value
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

        try
        {
            word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            word.Visible = false;
            word.ScreenUpdating = false;
            doc = word.Documents.Open(wordDocPath);
            pdfPath = wordDocPath.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");

            doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
                        pdfPath,
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                        OptimizeFor: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen,
                        BitmapMissingFonts: true, DocStructureTags: false);

            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)doc).Close();
            ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            }

            if (word != null)
            {
                ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        // Get the top stack frame
        var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
        // Get the line number from the stack frame
        var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

        throw new Exception("Line Number: " + line.ToString() + "  " + ex.ToString());
    }
    return pdfPath;
}
```

Comment: Well what fails in the c# code? IS the error something to do with  "cannot access object from a different thread then it was created on"?

Comment: from c# it throws Object reference not set to an instance of the object error.
further when tested using python, I was able to zero in on the line where it breaks, it fails to initialize document object at below line

doc = word.Documents.Open(wordDocPath);

due to running on background process without UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Got to know below answer from my colleague Anders.

Seconds answer here [Open and modify Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253215/open-and-modify-word-document)  says Microsoft does not support unattended autmation this way. 
It also suggests using http://freeword.codeplex.com/​​

I have just verified that this script works - also from a job / background process:

Although this is not a free software, but it works on background process.
It can be easily ported to c# as well, as it is a .net dll.

import clr

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\e-iceblue\Spire.Doc-FE\Bin\NET4.0\Spire.Doc.dll")

from Spire.Doc import *

from Spire.Doc.Documents import *

from System.IO import DirectoryInfo, File, FileInfo, Path

def ConvertWordToPDFUsingSPIRE(wordDocFullPath):

```
"""

<Script>

<Author>SNI</Author>

<Description>Converts Word document to PDF.</Description>

<Parameters>

<Parameter name="wordDocFullPath" type="string">Word document full path.</Parameter>

</Parameters>

<ReturnValue type="string">PDF full path</ReturnValue>

</Script>

"""

wordDocInfo = FileInfo(wordDocFullPath)

pdfFullPath = Path.Combine(wordDocInfo.DirectoryName, wordDocInfo.Name.TrimEnd(wordDocInfo.Extension.ToCharArray()) + '.pdf')




document = Document();

document.LoadFromFile(wordDocFullPath);




# Convert Word to PDF



document.SaveToFile(pdfFullPath, FileFormat.PDF);
```