# How's memory allocated for a dynamic variable .net 4.0?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

dynamic is a implicit or explicit type allocation ? How memory allocation occurs for dynamic variables in context of below example at runtime.

dyanmic impact on type safety as C# is type safe language.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                                                
        dynamic dynamicVar = 10;
        dynamicVar = true;
        dynamicVar = "hello world";
        // compiles fine
        int index = dynamicVar.IndexOf("world");                        
    }        
}
```

Comment: Below are some of the discussions on `stack` which might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478387/dynamic-and-performance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable of type `dynamic` is effectively a variable of type `object` as far as the CLR is concerned. It only affects the *compiler*, which makes any operations using a `dynamic` expression go through execution-time binding.

That binding process itself will use extra local variables etc (take a look in ILDASM, Reflector or something similar and you'll be staggered) but in terms of `dynamicVar` itself, the code you've got is just like having an `object` variable - with appropriate boxing for the `int` and `bool` values.

Comment: Thanks Jon .. but I want to ask one question in above code that, at runtime compiler uses reflection to understand the type on bases of value and evaluate the method "IndexOf" or it directly cast type based on value type.

Comment: @Deepak: Yes, it uses reflection basically. (For types implementing IDynamicMetaObjectProvider it will do rather different work, but for "simple" types it's effectively just reflection.)