# When to use List<dynamic> instead of List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, dynamic

In code review I have found interesting construction:

```
public ActionResult SeatMap(string name)
{
   var equimpment = this.CustomResourcesCache.GetAllEquipment(name);

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
   {
      List<dynamic> all = new List<dynamic>();
      foreach (var item in equimpment)
      {
         all.Add(item.Tag[0]);
      }
      return CachedResult(new { SeatMaps = all } );
     }
     return CachedResult(new { SeatMaps = equimpment.Where(o => o.Key == name).Count()>0?equimpment.Where(o => o.Key == name).First().Tag:new List<dynamic>() });
   }
```

I am just wondering why they used List <<[dynamic]>> instead of List<<[T]>> and is there any other solution instead of this one.

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you need to learn about dynamic. Then you can answer to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'dynamic' type in C# 4.0 used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for)

Comment: @Dilshod I don't think you understood the question. It isn't about `dynamic` but why it was used at all.

Comment: The code is horrible altogether, but I think @Panagiotis is right about the lazy part. And the offtopic part as well. We can't know why the original developer chose to use dynamic. In practice you hardly ever need it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Code explanation is off-topic for [CR.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not saying it is about dynamics. I said if you understood dynamics then you could have answered your own question.

Comment: I also suppose it was lazyness/whrong understannding on `dynamic`-keyword. You can however also write `List<whateverYourTypeOfTagIs>`

Comment: @Dilshod I understand dynamics and I don't think there's a reason for this code. Laziness, or sloppy coding of `CachedResults` makes more sense

Comment: @Dilshod It seems to me that they used wrong data structure here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about explaining existing code, not fixing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one rare scenario in which I would find this code acceptable.

Let's say `GetAllEquipment` returns a list of `Equipment`. `Equipment` does not contain the `Key` property that this code wants, but serves as a base class for various equipment classes, all of which have the `Key` property, but they don't share an interface.
In that case, there is no `T` that you can put in `List<T>`.

Now, if you own the code for `Equipment` and its children, the solution would be to create a shared interface with `Key` inside (and use this interface as your `T`).

But if you don't own the code, like if it's a third party library, then using `List<dynamic>` seems acceptable, with the understanding that future changes to that library might break your code (i.e if they introduce a new child to `Equipment` which doesn't have the `Key` property).