# Using C# dynamic typing in Unity 5.3.1f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ironpython, dynamic-typing

I have written code for my game that need to run a function of my python code. I am using Ironpython for my project.
However, when I am trying to use C# dynamic typing to call a function in the code below, it compiles but I get the following error from the Internals:

> " Assets/Scripts/WordSearchAlgorithm.cs(37,29): error CS1502:
>   The best overloaded method match for
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object>>.Create(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)'
>   has some invalid arguments " "
>   Assets/Scripts/WordSearchAlgorithm.cs(37,29): error CS1503: Argument
>   '#1' cannot convert 'object' expression to type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder' " "
>   Assets/Scripts/WordSearchAlgorithm.cs(37,61): error CS0234: The type
>   or namespace name 'RuntimeBinder' does not exist in the namespace
>   `Microsoft.CSharp'. Are you missing an assembly reference?  "
>   Assets/Scripts/WordSearchAlgorithm.cs(37,61): error CS1502: The best
>   overloaded method match for 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite>.Create(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)' has some invalid arguments

I think mono doesn't support this. Could you please give me a solution to help me?

```
static public void StartSearchAlgorithm()
{
    List < string > myList = new List < string > ()
    {
        "fxie",
         "amlo",
         "ewbx",
         "astu"
    };
    var ironPythonRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime();
    try
    {
        //Load the Iron Python file/script into the memory
        //Should be resolve at runtime
        dynamic loadIPython = ironPythonRuntime.UseFile("C:/py.py");
        //Invoke the method and print the result
        loadIPython.BoggleWords(myList, loadIPython.MakeTrie("C:/words.txt")); // here is my problem to calling function from python that unity logError
        //    Debug.Log(string.Format("dd", loadIPython.BoggleWords(myList, loadIPython.MakeTrie("C:/words.txt"))));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses the Mono 2.0 version of .NET, which is similar to .NET 3.5. `dynamic` was introduced in [.NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for), so Unity will probably not compile.

There is the option to change Mono 2.0 sub to Mono 2.0 full in the Player Settings, but I don't know if that supports `dynamic`. At least you can try.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to change Mono 2.0 sub to Mono 2.0 full in the Player Settings but error still exist

Comment: Then it is not supported in Mono 2.0. Also see this answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/686244/using-c-dynamic-typing-with-unity-434f1.html

Comment: Thanks Marnix for your Answering , I had seen this topic before but like code above. I want to call my Python function that without using C# dynamic typing do not work . I don't know maybe should change my coding

Comment: Can you find an IronPython library that uses .NET 3.5 maybe?

Comment: I had used IronPython 2.6 from C#4.0 , but unity had errors for its Libraries

Comment: IronPython 2.7.5 seems to have Net35 dll's as well. Try to reference those in your project and see if it doesn't use `dynamic`.