# Cannot implicitly convert "string" to "object" error?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to paste some text in a word file in c# and I tried this code from a stackoverflow post:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = null;
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
var filePath = @"H:\5555\Documents\Doc1.doc";
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);
Bookmark bkm = wordDoc.Bookmarks["name_field"];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = bkm.Range;
rng.Text = "Adams Laura"; //Get value from any where
```

So I get this error: Cannot implicitly convert "string" to "object" when I run this line.

> "Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath);"

But I have no idea what kind of object I have to use.

Comment: Try converting it explicitly, e.g. (object)filePath

Comment: Here's something that you should find useful. I think @Alex has already answered your question but this could also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for/2690837#2690837 - look at the answer from Lasse V. Karlsen.

Comment: A string is an object so i don't unerstand that error

Comment: i tried your code and change path of doc, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word's COM world can do things "pure" C# doesn't "like"/understand. One of those things is optional parameters. C# uses the concept "overloading" when a method can accept a different number and/or combination of parameters; the classic VB/COM world has a single method with optional parameters. So the PIAs present these to C# as data type `object` that need to be passed "by reference". If the parameter is not used, then `ref Type.Missing` is passed.

Newer versions of C# can accomodate the classic VB/COM idiosyncracies a bit better, but when you run into something you describe try:

```
object oFilePath = filePath;
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref oFilePath);
```

If you get another error, look at Intellisense for the `Open` method for the version of Word you're programming against and add `ref Type.Missing` for the remaining parameters listed in the Intellisense "tip".