# Is there a vb equivalent to the c# dynamic object

Tags: c#, vb.net

I just came across [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53662/oauth-jwt-token-bearer-flow-returns-invalid-client-credentials) snippet where the thread opener used

public static dynamic GetAccessToken()

I found out [what it is good for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for) and that it was implemented in C# 4.0 but I could not find an equivalent in vb.net. Is it just `Object` or is there something else that suits better?

Comment: @mason No, `dynamic` is *not* an `ExpandoObject`.  `dynamic` is just a way of turning off static typing.  `ExpandoObject` is an object that's more useful when there isn't static typing.  You can still use `dynamic` with any other object, and `ExpandoObject` without using `dynamic`.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the correction. I tend to avoid dynamic myself as much as possible.

Comment: The equivalent *is* using 'Object' with Option Strict Off.  The 'dynamic' keyword was added to C# to replicate this VB 'feature' in C#.