# Setting a flexible Model in Web API for Get controller

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a simple Web API with only `GET` controller. Currently,I have the following model, which is the return type of my GET controller:

```
namespace _1WebApplication.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class SystemStatus
    {        
        public string SystemName { get; set; }       
        public string Good { get; set; }      
        public string Bad { get; set; }        
        public string MachineStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my GET api looks like this:

```
// GET api/values
public SystemStatus Get()
{
    //Read the data from XML file here
    string systemName = "REW_1";
    string good = "60";
    string bad = "10";
    string machineStatus = "Running";

    var SystemStatus = new SystemStatus
    {
        SystemName = systemName,
        Good = goodCount,
        Bad = badCount,
        MachineStatus = machineStatus
    };

    return SmartscanStatus;    
}
```

**QUESTION:** In the above case, I can return the values of only 4 variables (i.e. `SystemName` , `Good` , `Bad` and `MachineStatus` ). 
But actually, I want to read the parameters and values from an XML file and then return those values.

For example, I have this XML file

```
<SystemName>mysystem</SystemName>
<Good>60</Good>
<Bad>10</Bad>
<MachineStatus>stop</MachineStatus>
<IpAddress>127.0.0.1</IpAddress>        
<Username>username</Username>       
<Password>password</Password>
```

In this case, the XML file has some more variable but since my model is fixed, I am not able to return them. So, how to make my model flexible/dynamic so that I can decide the variable names and values from an XML file.

Answer (score -1):

Read the `XML` with [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview) and convert it into [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for) object

[ExpandoObject](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/expandoobject-in-c-sharp-40) provides a way to construct dynamic properties.

```
public SystemStatus Get()
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData); 
    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xmlDoc);
    dynamic dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonStr);

    return dynamicObject;
}
```

Comment: But where should I define the return type i.e. `SystemStatus`? in Models? and how?

Comment: ExpandoObject will be creating that for you

Comment: so, you mean that I don't have to make any changes in the Models?

Comment: It is not going to use `SystemStatus` model. Did you check `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: It throws a runtime error at the `return` statement.