# How to Access elements in a List<T> when T is only stored in a Type Variable?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'll try to make this clear:

I have an object of type System.Object that contains a List of things.  The things are determined at runtime.  Currently, I'm able to find out the type of things contained in the list, but I can't figure out how to access them.

Here's a code example where "o" is the List of things in question:

Example:

```
//Assume at this point in code, we have access to "o"
//which is type System.Object

Type thingType = thing.GetType();
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type listOfThingsType = listType.MakeGenericType(thingType);

if (o.GetType() == listOfThingsType)
{
    //Now I know o contains a list of things
    //...but how do I access them and work with their members?

    //foreach thing in o
    //   operate on thing through reflection
}
```

**EDIT (more details):**
I'm using reflection to access property members of things.  I don't know what the property names are. I don't need to be able to use normal C# syntax.  I just need a way to access the things so I can use reflection on them as individual objects.

Comment: If you only know the type dynamically, you can only access the members dynamically e.g. `foreach(object thing in (IList)o) { ... }`.

Comment: Foreach(var object in o) ...

Comment: Are the Types of the _things_ in your list known to you?  So you don't know the order or how many, but they are from a predefined list of Types that you are aware of?

Comment: @Martin If I understand your question, the answer is yes.  There is a limited set of things they could be.  Unfortunately, this code needs to be able to function without referencing them here as strong types.  I can access a variable list of the possible types, though, if that's helpful.

Comment: Where does `thing` come from in the code above? And is it the same type that `o` contains? It might be helpful if you included some sample data.

Comment: @RufusL thing is just an object.  And it was derived through reflection.  The point of the code example is that you have to assume you don't know where thing came from.

Comment: It sounds like you should be working with interfaces or a type hierarchy. Otherwise what is the point even if you are not sure what you will be calling...

Comment: @RufusL The existing code demonstrates that "thing" is indeed of the same type that "o" contains.  That's the point of the Generic list construction followed by the if test.

Comment: @Igor the point is that this code is for an experimental serializer that exposes tremendous ease to its users and makes no assumptions about the types it will be used on.  But some of the underlying code is quite a stumbling block for me.  This particular case is an example.  I seem to be at a wall.

Comment: Use *dynamic* so you can use normal C# syntax.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using reflection to access properties via PropertyInfo.  Unless there's something I don't know, my understanding is that "dynamic" is for when you already know what the member names will be at compile time.  All examples of "dynamic" I've seen, look like PHP or other scripty lang as in here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for

Comment: [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) implements [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.8). If all you need is access to the instances that make up the list for serialization (or whatever) use `List` instead of `List<T>` as it seems like the actual type might not really matter. Of course that might depend on the serializer you are using too (you mentioned that in your comment?).

Comment: You do know what the member names are, after you checked that it is a `List<T>`.

Comment: @Igor I think what you're saying sounds like it might fix the problem. Could you post some code with an example?  It might seem obvious to you, but it's not to me, which is why I asked to begin with. :)

Comment: @HansPassant Oh! Ok I thought you were suggesting to use "dynamic" for the thing. You're saying if I use dynamic on the object o, then I can access it as if its a normal List with foreach.

Comment: @HansPassant I added a possible solution in the question to clarify if that's what you're describing.  I tried it out in Visual Studio and the compiler certainly thinks its fine (haven't tried running it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) implements [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.8). If all you need is access to the instances that make up the list for serialization (or whatever) use `List` instead of `List<T>` as it seems like the actual type might not really matter. Of course that might depend on the serializer you are using too (you mentioned that in your comment?).

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/34DCvK)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public class MyType 
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public MyType(){}
        public MyType(string name) {
          this.Name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name ?? "empty";
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();
        list.Add(new MyType("One"));
        list.Add(new MyType("Two"));
        DoSomethingWithUnknown(list);
    }

    public static void DoSomethingWithUnknown(object argList)
    {
        var list = (IList)argList;
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("As object: " + item);
            dynamic itm = item;
            Console.WriteLine("As dynamic: " + itm.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Igor!  I'll look at this more later. :)

Comment: Thanks, Igor.  After much love and having my library working, I was informed that I needed to target .Net Standard.  So the use of "dynamic" keyword went out the window! I had to change all my code to use the solution like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to HansPassant, who suggested using dynamic.

Here is the solution:

```
//Assume at this point in code, we have access to "o"
//which is type System.Object

Type thingType = thing.GetType();
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type listOfThingsType = listType.MakeGenericType(thingType);

if (o.GetType() == listOfThingsType)
{
    //Now I know o contains a list of things
    //...but how do I access them and work with their members?

    dynamic oList = o;
    foreach(object thing in oList)
    {
        //operate on thing through reflection
    }
}
```