# Why assigning byte value to a dynamic variable changes dynamic to byte data type in c#?

Tags: c#

In an interview i was asked to define output of the code below :

```
    byte data= 100;
    dynamic val = data;
    Console.WriteLine(val.GetType())
```

I answered that it would not change data type of `val` variable but when i tested in a console,actually it did !
`val` variable changed to System.Byte

But more interesting is that when you change `val` data type to int32,Nothing changed
it is still `System.Int32` !

```
    byte data= 100;
    int val = data;
    Console.WriteLine(val.GetType())
```

What is the logic of these conversions?

Comment: _dynamic != decimal_ Your title talks about _decimal_ but your code uses _dynamic_

Comment: The data type in the first snippet didn't change.  `byte` is the same thing as `System.Byte`.  In the second you actually did change the data type

Comment: This is really duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690623/what-is-the-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0-used-for... but since we have 2M rep answers it probably better to keep it separate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `dynamic` means.  `dynamic` is a synonym for `object`.  Would you be surprised at the behaviour of your program if you replaced `dynamic` with `object`? If not, then your question is answered; if yes, then explain in more detail what your confusion is.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the *variable itself* is still `dynamic` as far as C# is concerned, and `object` as far as the runtime is concerned.

At execution time, the *value* of `val` is a boxed `byte` - because you asked it to copy the value from a `byte` variable.

In your second snippet, you're just using the fact that there's an implicit conversion from `byte` to `int`. It's not that "it is still `System.Int32`" - the value of `data` is a `byte`, and that is widened to `int` via an implicit conversion. That *is* changing the type.

Answer (score 4):

[Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types)

> The dynamic type differs from object in that operations that contain
>   expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the
>   compiler. The compiler packages together information about the
>   operation, and that information is later used to evaluate the
>   operation at run time. As part of the process, variables of type
>   dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore, **type
>   dynamic exists only at compile time**, not at run time.

Why does `Object.GetType()` return `byte`? [Because](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_GetType) `Object.GetType()`:

> Returns the **exact runtime type** of the current instance.

And why  does `byte` become `System.Int32`?

You are assigning `byte` value to `int` variable and this is why `val` has type `int`:

```
byte data= 100;
int val = data;
Console.WriteLine(val.GetType())
```

`Byte` is a range from 0 to 255. 
`int` is a range from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

So it is eligible to assign `byte` range to `int` range