# Read value from dynamic property from json payload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a simple model that I used as a request payload

```
public class CommandRequest
{
    public CommandType Type { get; set; }
    public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

In controller action I need to read some property from dynamic `Attributes`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Commands([FromBody] CommandRequest requestBody)
{
    string name = requestBody.Attributes.Name;
    ...
}
```

Got the following exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
```

How can I read that property?

Comment: the [HttpPost("id")] should be [HttpPost("{id}")] try it like this

Comment: @BasselEid Thanks but it is not a problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declaring something as `dynamic` doesn't guarantee that the resulting concrete object implements [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider?view=netcore-3.1) and allows for runtime definition of properties.  Rather, `dynamic` simply means an `object` to which all compile-time checking has been turned off, and so all method and member references to it will be resolved in runtime. See:

- [What Is Dynamic?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-dynamic-net-understanding-the-dynamic-keyword-in-csharp-4#what-is-dynamic)
- [What is the 'dynamic' type in C# 4.0 used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690623/3744182)

Now, when you deserialize a JSON object to a member declared as `dynamic` with Json.NET, Newtonsoft will chose [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) as the concrete type to which to deserialize.  As its base type [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` you can do things like `requestBody.Attributes.Name` and the .Net runtime will forward the property resolution to the `JObject` which will look the property up inside its list of properties.  However, this doesn't happen automatically, Newtonsoft had to enhance `JToken` to make dynamic property access possible.

`System.Text.Json`, however, does not have built-in support for deserializing free-form JSON to some custom type implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, so you will need to use the compile-time methods of the actual type returned, viz. [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=netcore-3.1), to access the JSON data contained therein:

```
var name = requestBody.Attributes.GetProperty("Name").ToString();
```

Or, you could cast it for clarity:

```
var name = ((JsonElement)requestBody.Attributes).GetProperty("Name").ToString();
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UBhIYu).

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use the GetProperty method on the JsonElement to get the property you desire.
2. You can deserialize with JsonConvert.Deseralize("jsonpayload") to the model of Attributes and get Name directly with the "." notation.
3. You can deserialize to Dictionary<string,string> and get the property name as Dict["Name"].

Comment: Because dynamic objects sent via body arrive to the controller as a JsonObject. to access their properties as you would normally you have to deserialize them to their correct model or use JsonObject methods to get the property first and its value later with a "GetString" or similar. Dynamic objects kinda "loose" their original type when you pass them, you need to cast/deserialize/etc. them to something you can use.