# How to deserialize dynamic Json objects?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am currently receiving the following JSON response from my api:

```
{"Lastname":["ERRLASTNAMEEMPTY"],"Firstname":["ERRFIRSTNAMEEMPTY"]}
```

Note that the above response is dynamic - i.e sometimes I can have FirstName, sometimes LastName, sometimes both. This response is based on the validation of data.

My question is - is there a way to deserialize this response using JsonSerializer.DeSerialize?

I have tried to use it like this but it does not work:

```
var errorBody = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(body, serializerOptions);
```

Comment: But it's not completely dynamic, right?  Sometimes you have `Lastname`, sometimes you have `Firstname`, and you just need one or the other or both, right?

Comment: Also, `System.Text.Json` does not currently support deserializing to dynamic objects, see [Read value from dynamic property from json payload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64036207/3744182).

Comment: Use ExpandoObject instead of dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string[]>>(body, serializerOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with dynamic JSON objects with `JObject` like that:

```cs
var data = JObject.Parse(body);
```

And later you are able to access values with `data["Lastname"]?.Value<string>();` and such, the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(body, serializerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// introduce a dynamic object from a string :
// {"UrlCheckId":581,"Request":{"JobId":"a531775f-be19-4c78-9717-94aa051f6b23","AuditId":"b05016f5-51c9-48ba-abcc-ec16251439e5","AlertDefinitionId":108,"JobCreated":"2022-05-20T07:09:56.236656+01:00","UrlJobId":0,"BatchJobId":"e46b9454-2f90-407d-9243-c0647cf6502d"},"JobCreated":"2022-05-20T07:10:21.4097268+01:00"}
// ...The UrlCheckId is an int primitive and Request is our UrlCheckJobRequest object.

dynamic msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message);

// to access an int (primitive) property:
int id = msg.UrlCheckId;

// to access an object, you might have to serialize the request into a string first...
var r = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg.Request);

// ... and then deserialize into an object
UrlCheckJobRequest request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UrlCheckJobRequest>(r);
```