# in c# Is there a method to cast an instance of a subclass by string?

Tags: c#, casting, subclass

For example, say you have

```
class Item { }
class Book: Item { }
```

and you have an object declaration such as

```
Item myBook = new Book();
```

you could cast it to the subclass with the code

```
Book myBookCasted = myBook as Book;
```

What I would like to know is if there is a method, probably with reflection, to cast the instance to the subclass with a string instead of the type name?  Something like:

```
Book myBookCasted = myBook as "Book";
```

But with the correct syntax of course.

Thanks.

Comment: Then how would you determine the variable type (on the left hand side)? You can do something similar via Reflection, but that gets a lot more verbose than what you want

Comment: I agree with @UnholySheep.  If you already have access to the type `Book`, why bother trying to write syntax such as `myBook as "Book"`?  Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and there's more to the story.  Why do you think you want such syntax?  Is there a deeper issue you're trying to solve, and you think this approach is the way to do it?

Comment: Yes, firstly I can use var instead of the subclass name, secondly my app a game will have dynamic data stored as text files, so being able to cast to a specific subclass from the string name of the subclass from the file is a potential requirement.  Actually this may also include an instantiation situation; Basically I want smarter RTTI then merely relying on  a list of if statements "if (myvar is Book)".

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer to closer align with the way you intent to use this? You might have overlooked a pattern that you can use instead of ending up trying to solve this using reflection.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to serialise/deserialise data.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MorphTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Item myBook = new Book();
            dynamic myBookCasted = Convert.ChangeType(myBook, Type.GetType("MorphTest.Book"));
            Console.WriteLine(myBookCasted.GetType()); // Prints "MorphTest.Book"
        }
    }

    public class Item { }
    public class Book: Item { }
}
```

The only things to keep in mind is, you must be using .NET 4.0 or higher and you must use the fully qualified name (e.g. instead of just `"Book"`, it must be `"MorphTest.Book"`. Obviously you'll change `MorphTest` to whatever namespace the class is in.

Comment: "Could" someone use `dynamic` for this? Sure. "Should" someone? Probably not.  Here's a good explanation for [when and when not to use `dynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2690837/3791245).  The answer might want to point out some of the ideas in that link about what `dynamic` is really best used for.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I understand what `dynamic` should be used for. And to make it clear, I am not encouraging the OP to program like this. I am simply pointing out that there is a way to do it, to answer his question. Should it be used? Hell, no.

Comment: No worries - I didn't mean to imply _you_ didn't know what `dynamic` should be used for, but _future readers_ might not.  The answer as written didn't acknowledge these details about `dynamic`, hence the link and suggestion to update the answer with that info.